# Spring Boot 1.2.4.RELEASE cannot generate a simple Startup Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot version 1.2.4.RELEASE to generate a simple web project. The full Url for creating this project is:

http://start.spring.io/starter.zip?name=demo3&groupId=org.test&artifactId=demo3&version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT&description=Demo+project+for+Spring+Boot&packageName=demo3&type=maven-project&packaging=jar&javaVersion=1.7&language=java&bootVersion=1.2.4.RELEASE&dependencies=web

The download starter project opened in the STS 3.6.4.RELEASE with tons of errors: Missing artifact, ArtifactDescriptorException from the pom.xml file.

However, if I use version 1.1.12.RELEASE of the Spring Boot, I have no problem to create the startup project.

Is this a bug in the 1.2.4.RELEASE of the Spring Boot? I doubt it.

Comment: The project looks fine. The problem is most probably in your local environment (maybe Maven can't access public repositories to download the 1.2.4 versions, and 1.1.12 is already in your local Maven repository).

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Yes, I see.  Maven didn't download all spring-*-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar files successfully.  I had to re-download them again to my local repo.

Answer (score 0):

The project is OK.
Please to check your local env, specially connexion, maven configuration (setting.xml), ...etc

Good luck